# Rational Canonical Form over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, modules

We have a structure theorem for f.g. modules over $R$, whenever $R$ is a PID. In the case of $R=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ($p$ a prime), the structure theorem can be used to obtain the rational canonical form for matrices over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

> I am interested in some kind of canonical form for matrices over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$. Is there such a canonical form in the literature?
>
> This question naturally leads to a more concrete one: What is known about the structure of f.g. modules over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

If I have a matrix $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$, the relevant $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module is the ``vector space'' $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^n$, on which $x$ acts as multiplication by $A$.

Comment: A partial answer (cyclic modules killed by $p^2$) but which probably grasps part of the idea how to do more generally: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268530/classification-of-the-quotients-of-the-ring-z-4-x/269597#269597

Comment: You can lift $A$ to a matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Then you have $U,V\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $UBV$ is a Smith normal form. Since $U,V$ have determinant $\pm 1$, they still are invertible modulo $p^k$.

By reduction mod $p^k$,  there exists $U',V'\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$ sucht that $U'AV'=diag (\bar{d}_1,\ldots,\bar{d}_s, \bar{0},\cdots, \bar{0})$, with $d_1\mid\cdots\mid d_s$.
I kinda remember that in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$, we have $(\bar{a})=(\bar{b})\iff \bar{a}=\bar{u} \ \bar{b}, $ where $\bar{u}$ is a unit.Then **maybe** you can have some kind of uniqueness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is open, and not because nobody tried. For instance, it is known that the number of similarity classes in $M_n(\mathbf Z/p^2 \mathbf Z)$ is equal to the number of simultaneous conjugacy classes of pairs of *commuting* matrices in $M_n(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)$ (S. J AMBOR and W. PLESKEN , *Normal forms for matrices over uniserial rings of length two*, J. Algebra 358 (2012), 250–256). For small values of $n$, exact formulae are given in my paper in IUMJ *[Similarity of matrices over local rings of length two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1512/iumj.2015.64.5500)* with Pooja Singla and Steven Spallone, which is also available on the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6157).

From the classification/structure theorem point of view, these are *wild problems*, so you should not expect a good answer. You will find a discussion of the history and other results on this problem in the intro to my paper mentioned above.