# Conjugacy class representatives for the automorphism group of a finite abelian group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups

Given a finite abelian group $A$, I'd like a list of conjugacy class representatives for its automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(A)$.

In fact, it's not important that I have exactly one representative from each conjugacy class, as long as each class is represented at least once and the list of elements is much smaller than the whole group.

I know that when $A$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group, ${\rm Aut}(A)$ is a general linear group and rational canonical form does what I need [e.g. Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra (3rd Ed), Section 12.2].  Is there a generalisation of this that works for arbitrary finite abelian groups?

Comment: Every automorphism preserves every $p$-Sylow subgroup.  Thus, the automorphism group is the direct product group of the automorphism groups of the $p$-Sylow subgroups.  Thus, every conjugacy class in the automorphism group is uniquely determined by its projections to conjugacy classes in each of the automorphism groups of the $p$-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Yes, there's an immediate reduction to the case of an abelian $p$-group;

Comment: Thanks both, I see how that works.  The general abelian $p$-group case still seems tricky though.

Comment: This is a very general question and almost impossible to answer. The two papers by Bidwell et. al. "Automorphisms of direct products of finite groups I,II" give some intuition about the structure of automorphism group of finite abelian groups.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out.  I'll also think about how to narrow the question so that an answer will still help me with what I'm working on.

Comment: If we fix the exponent of the abelian group, say $p^k$, then this is equivalent to classification of finite-length-modules over $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k) [T]$. Maybe a wild problem?

Comment: @FriederLadisch Yes, it's wild: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291815

Comment: Well, I now know what a wild problem is, and that I shouldn't feel bad for not managing to solve the problem myself.  Thanks both.